# LINQ - more than or equal to

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Part of the code:

```
...where se.DateFrom >= pDateFrom && se.DateTo <= pDateTo select se...
```

Does not work. There is no any error but the To and From days do not get returned.

How do I query "more than or equal to" and "less than or equal to"?

Thanks :)

Comment: LINQ-to-Objects? LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Assuming its linq to objects, you probably have a time attached to your date that is messing you up.  (.Today is your friend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your "dates" potentially contain a time element? If so, try something like this:

```
where se.DateFrom >= pDateFrom.Date && se.DateTo.Date <= pDateTo
```

Comment: Yes, they are of type DateTime?

Comment: where se.DateFrom.Date >= pDateFrom.Date  && se.DateTo.Date <= pDateTo.Date

This one works ok